# Advance Search : Airtable to Zapier

Tags: zapier, airtable

this is my first post!

We want to create an airtable integration: when an ID in a certain column is an ODD number, so we will automatically update the STATUS for another column. Have googled and searched but perhaps couldn't find the right answer, especially for the Search Formula field. Appreciate any help for this!

Huge Thanks!

Comment: What is the trigger for your Zap? Is it Airtable or a different service?

Comment: Hai! My Trigger for Zap is "A new record in view"--but I want to create a logic here:
1. For an odd number: I will give status "A"
2. For an even number: I will give status "B".

Answer (score 1):

Within your Airtable table, you can create a new formula field called "Is Odd."  The formula within that field would then be `IF(MOD({ID}, 2) = 1, "True", "False")`.  If the `ID` field mod 2 is equal to 1, then the field is odd, otherwise, it is not.

You could just use this Airtable formula logic to assign a status.  Change "True" and "False" to whatever your status values are.  You can then group, filter and sort your records based on the values in that field.  For more info on Airtable formulas: https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/203255215-Formula-Field-Reference

If you really need to continue with Zapier, you have a couple of different options for how to proceed.  One way would be to use the "Path" helper step to split your workflow.  Zapier should follow Path A if the `Is Odd` field of the record is equal to the string `True` and Path B if the field is equal to the string `False`.  Down each path, you can then use the Update Record Airtable action to update the record with the correct status. The "Path" step requires a "Professional" account with Zapier.

The other option requires a "Pro" account (which is cheaper than a Professional account).  You can create two different Zaps, one for Odd IDs and one for Even IDs.  Use the Filter helper step in Zapier to then only execute the Odd Zap if `Is Odd` is equal to the string `True` and the Even Zap if `Is Odd` is equal to the string `False`.  Each Zap can then use the Update Record Airtable action to update the record with the correct status.

I definitely recommend using functions within Airtable to manage this.  No reason to include a third party if you don't have to!